# find and replace each line - bash script

Tags: macos, bash, replace

I want to delete in a file each line beginning by '#'. I ran that (I am using osx)

```
 sed -i '' -e 's/#.*/d' file
```

but I get this error message :

```
sed: 1: "s/#.*/d
": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Comment: You need `sed -i '/^#/d' file`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: `sed -i '/^#/d' file` → `sed: 1: "file": invalid command code f`

Comment: @GarethRees you probably don't have GNU sed that handles the `-i` option...

Comment: @GarethRees Funny that my GNU `sed` is happy with the command I gave... are you sure you didn't mistype it? Besides, that command is exactly the one you gave in your answer `:D`.

Comment: The OP is on OS X, where the `sed` is BSD-ish, and that means that the `-i` option requires an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`s`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) command in [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) means "substitute" and it takes *two* arguments:

```
s/pattern/replacement/
```

What you want to do is just to *match* lines starting with `#` and delete them, so you need the `sed` program:

```
/^#/d
```

Note that the pattern needs to start with [`^` (meaning "start of line")](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) otherwise it will match a `#` anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Gareth Rees above, the correct command is:

```
sed '/^#/ d' file
```

This good [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) tutorial contains your question as an example:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-30